# How do I check the answer of a clicked button to see if it matches the correct answer found within an array of objects in JavaScript for a trivia game

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function, button

I have a trivia app that is almost complete. It contains an array of objects (being imported from a separate JavaScript file) containing all of my questions and four possible answers. I have a function that generates a random question from that array, stores the value into a global variable called `randomQuestion` and populates the HTML buttons with four possible answers.

I previously used the `onClick` event for each button within the HTML. That worked, however, there were too many questions to include in the primary JavaScript file. I moved them and exported/imported them to the app’s primary file. When I did this my `checkAnswer` function no longer worked, and I got the `Uncaught TypeError` warning. I was informed that in order to fix this I needed to remove the `onClick` events  from the HTML file and `addEventListener`s to the buttons within the primary file.

Within the primary file I have captured each button with `getElementById` and have added `click` event listeners to each of the button variables. When the button is clicked the `checkAnswer` function should check if the selected answer is equal to the correct answer, and `console.log` “correct” or “incorrect”.

My problem is that I don't know how to capture the value of the answer button that is clicked and compare that to the correct answer value within the current `randomQuestion`. The code below is what I’m working with.

```
<button id="answers-btn-1" class="answers-btn"></button>
<button id="answers-btn-2" class="answers-btn"></button>
<button id="answers-btn-3" class="answers-btn"></button>
<button id="answers-btn-4" class="answers-btn"></button>
```

```
function checkAnswer() {
  answer = randomQuestion.answers;
  if(answer.correct === true) {
    console.log("Correct!");
  } else {
    console.log("Incorrect");
  }
}
```

```
export const questions = [
    {
        question: 'What year did the United States gain independence?',
        answers: [
          { text: '1776', correct: true },
          { text: '1676', correct: false },
          { text: '1576', correct: false },
          { text: `1476', correct: false }
        ]
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating the HTML up-front this example builds the HTML from the question/answer data, adds it to the DOM, and adds *one* listener to a buttons container which (using [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/)) captures events from its child elements (the buttons) as they "bubble up" the DOM.

To steer away from global variables `checkAnswer` accepts the array of answers and *returns* a new function ([closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)) when it is called.

```
answers.addEventListener('click', checkAnswer(question.answers));
```

*That* function is assigned to the listener and called when the listener is fired.

```js
const questions=[{question:"What year did the United States gain independence?",answers:[{text:"1776",correct:true},{text:"1676",correct:false},{text:"1576",correct:false},{text:"1476",correct:false}]},{question:"What star does Earth orbit?",answers:[{text:"Moon",correct:false},{text:"Proxima Centauri",correct:false},{text:"Sun",correct:true},{text:"Roy Orbison",correct:false}]}];

// `checkAnswers` accepts the answers for the question
// and returns a new function (closure) that is assigned to the
// listener which fires when any of the child elements
// (the buttons) of the container `.answers` is clicked
// The closure keeps a reference to the answers when it is returned
function checkAnswer(answers) {
  return function(e) {

    // If the clicked child element is a button
    // get its textContent, `find` the correct answer
    // from the answers array, destructure its text value
    // and then compare it to the textContent of the clicked button
    if (e.target.matches('.answer')) {
      const { textContent } = e.target;
      const { text } = answers.find(answer => answer.correct);
      if (textContent === text) {
        console.log('Correct');
      } else {
        console.log('Incorrect');
      }
    }
  }
}

// Accepts the question answers and builds
// the buttons HTML
function buildAnswers(answers) {
  return answers.map(answer => {
    return `<button class="answer">${answer.text}</button>`;
  }).join('');
}

// Builds the question which is added to the
// element with the `question` class. It adds the
// question to an <h3> elementm, and calls `buildAnswers`
// with the answers as an argument to return the answers HTML
// Note: `map` returns an array so we need to join into into
// a string
function buildQuestion(question) {
  return `
    <h3>${question.question}</h3>
    <section class="answers">
      ${buildAnswers(question.answers)}
    </section>
  `;
}

// Get a random number based on the length of
// the questions array
function rnd(questions) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * questions.length);
}

// The main function
// 1) Gets a random question from the array
// 2) Gets the question element
// 3) Creates the question HTML
// 4) Inserts the HTML into the question element
// 5) It grabs the answers container element
// 6) Adds an event listener to it which calls `checkAnswer`
// with the set of available answers as an argument, which
// returns a function that is used when a button is clicked
function main() {
  
  const question = questions[rnd(questions)];
  const el = document.querySelector('.question');
  const html = buildQuestion(question);
  el.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
  
  const answers = document.querySelector('.answers');
  answers.addEventListener('click', checkAnswer(question.answers));

}

// Call main
main();
```

```css
.answer { margin-right: 0.3em; border-radius: 5px; }
.answer:hover { cursor: pointer; background-color: lightblue;}
```

```html
<section class="question"></section>
```

Additional documentation

- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)
- [Template/string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: Thank you. It seems that your answer would require me to reprogram most of the current app. Is there a way to consolidate that code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use form with submit buttons

```js
const questions = [
    {
        question: 'What year did the United States gain independence?',
        answers: [
          { text: '1776', correct: true },
          { text: '1676', correct: false },
          { text: '1576', correct: false },
          { text: '1476', correct: false }
        ]
      }];
      
const currentQ = questions[0];

document.getElementById('question').textContent = currentQ.question;
const form = document.getElementById('form');
for (let i = 0; i < currentQ.answers.length; i++) {
  const btn = document.createElement('button');
  btn.type = 'submit';
  btn.textContent = currentQ.answers[i].text;
  btn.value = currentQ.answers[i].text;
  form.appendChild(btn);
}

function handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const answer = e.submitter.value;
  const correctAnswer = currentQ.answers.find(ans => ans.correct);
  console.log(answer === correctAnswer.text ? 'Correct' : 'Incorrect');
  
}
```

```html
<form id="form" onsubmit="handleSubmit(event)">
  <p id="question">question?</p>
</form>
```